# I want to create a virtual environment for Django project but when I do pip install Django it says requirement already satisfied

Tags: python, django

Every time I start a Django Project with `django-admin startproject projectName` I am getting this error:

```
PS F:\Going back to backend> django-admin startproject lecture3
django-admin : The term 'django-admin' is not recognized as the name of a
cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and 
try again.
```

Comment: you have to activate virtual environment to install django inside virtual environment. You  installed django in the system level  that's why it's says that already is installed

Comment: Try following this example for setting up and activating a virtual environment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/windows/#setting-up-a-virtual-environment